# How to add up election zone voting upto county level?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, spatial-join, aggregation

Sorry if it is a trivial question.

I am trying to add voting data from election zone up to county-level using spatial join tool, but I cannot figure out which relationship I should use. When I use Intersect, it seems data are being repeated (original sum:13198656 After spatial join:13921985). I also tried Contains, it seems data are being left then (original sum: After spatial join:12262146). I guess some election zones are intersecting between two counties. What should I do about it?

Comment: This isn't a trivial question if election zones overlap counties. If it's only slightly overlapping use polygon to point to gain the centroids of the election zones, which should be in the right county, intersect with counties then use summary statistics on the intersected points to accumulate the sum (statistics fields) for each county ID/Name (case field).

Comment: If you have more than a little overlap you will need to decide how to split the attributes; I have used density before: value per sq.m. then intersect and multiply the intersected area density by the final area - all things being equal a good choice but sometimes the population really falls on a small portion so density doesn't work because it's not consistent, in cases like these you will have to use your best judgement and **document your division method** to show those who follow how you got to the final numbers.